# Laravel 5.6 PasswordBroker change token duration time dynamically according to a specific situation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

What I'm trying to achieve is when we create a user, he receives a login mail with a link that is only valid for 6 hours or so. This is not enough, and in most cases, we have to manually set the password for the user.

The user should have 3 days for creating his first password.

However, when a user clicks on forgot the password, the 6-hour limit is enough (because that is something that he does consciously).

Here's what I have so far!

Our store function in the **UsersController** looks like this:

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
    {
        ...

        \DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $data) {

            $roles = $request->input('roles');
            $isInternal = $request->input('is_internal');
            $customers = $request->input('customers', []);

            /** @var User $user */
            $user = $this->userRepository->create($data);
            $user->assignRole($roles);

            if ($isInternal == false && !empty($customers)) {
                $user->customers()->sync($customers);
            }

            $token = app(PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($user);
            $user->notify(new AccountActivationNotification($token));
        });

        return $this->respond()->success([], "User successfully created.");
    }
```

Our **reset** and **forgot** functions:

```
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token');

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->passwordBroker->reset(
            $credentials,
            function ($user, $password) {
                $user->password = $password;
                $user->status = StatusesService::STATUS_ACTIVE;
                $user->email_verified_at = now();
                $user->save();
                event(new PasswordReset($user));
            }
        );

        return $response == $this->passwordBroker::PASSWORD_RESET
            ? $this->respond()->success()
            : $this->respond()->validationFailed(trans($response));
    }

    public function forgot(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->passwordBroker->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );
        return $response == $this->passwordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? $this->respond()->success([], "Your password has been reset, please check your inbox.")
            : $this->respond()->validationFailed(trans($response));
    }
```

We already set two different configuration in config/auth.php:

```
 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 4320, //3 days
        ],
        'users_fpassword' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1440, //6 hours
        ],
    ],
```

What can we do to dynamically change between the configurations that we have in the `config/auth.php` accordingly to the situation described at the beginning of the post?

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you looking for is how to set config value dynamically in Laravel you can easily do this using Laravel helper function.

```
config(['auth.passwords.users.expire' => 120]);
```

So in config file make it default 6 hrs expiration time.

```
 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1440, //6 hrs
        ],
    ],
```

and in controller function just add one line

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
    {
        ...

        \DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $data) {

            $roles = $request->input('roles');
            $isInternal = $request->input('is_internal');
            $customers = $request->input('customers', []);

            /** @var User $user */
            $user = $this->userRepository->create($data);
            $user->assignRole($roles);

            if ($isInternal == false && !empty($customers)) {
                $user->customers()->sync($customers);
            }

            config(['auth.passwords.users.expire' => 4320]);

            $token = app(PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($user);
            $user->notify(new AccountActivationNotification($token));
        });

        return $this->respond()->success([], "User successfully created.");
    }
```

Comment: Does this actually work? The expiry time in config is used along with the token `created_at` timestamp AFAIK. I don't think you can create dynamic expiries in the way described in this answer.

Comment: we are changing expire time at run time using config function. So it should work.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78eb4dabcc03e189620c16f436358d41d31ae11f/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php#L127

It uses the `created_at` timestamp along with the `expire` from config. It does not matter that you changed the config at the time of token creation

Comment: got your point need to update expire vaiable in DatabaseTokenRepository as well when we are chacking.
So this should not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, better solution for you is:

1. Changing scheme of `password_resets` table by adding field like `expire_at`, which stores expiring time of token.
2. Creating your own `TokenRepository`(implements `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface`). Inside it implement all logic: on token creating populate `expire_at` field, on token checking - verify that it's expiring time later than now.
3. Extend `PasswordBroker` by adding your own method, which allow you pass new token lifetime to TokenRepository.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another password reset configuration in config/auth.php like:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    'invites' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 1440,
    ],
],
```

This can later be used in your controller like:

```
if (!app('auth.password')->broker('invites')->tokenExists($user, $request->input('token'))) {
  return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

Well, adjust it to your needs. I tested this on laravel 6.x and it works correctly.